# how to open a div click on two button clicks one after other in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a problem regarding button click i have four buttons on click of two buttons back to back i want open div so based on different combination of clicks i want to open different divs

here is my html

```
    <button id="B">B</button>
    <button id="Q">Q</button>
    <button id="Ag">Ag</button>
    <button id="Cli">Cli</button>


<div id="BAg"></div>
<div id="BCli"></div>
<div id="QAg"></div>
<div id="QCli"></div>
```

so on click of `B` and `Ag` i want to open div with `id = "BAg"` and 
on click of `B` and `Cli` i want to open div with `id = "BCli"` and 
on click of `Q` and `Ag` i want to open div with `id = "QAg"` and
on click `Q` and `Cli` i want to open div with `id = "QCli"`

Here is jquery what i have tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#B").click(function(){
$("#Ag").click(function(){
alert("B Ag")
});
});

$("#B").click(function(){
$("#Cli").click(function(){
alert("B Cli")
});
});

$("#Q").click(function(){
$("#Ag").click(function(){
alert("Q Ag")
});
});

$("#Q").click(function(){
$("#Cli").click(function(){
alert("Q Cli")
});
});
});
```

so can we help me with this

Comment: You need to show that you tried something too

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava i have edited the question with jquery

Comment: Also, you do not have **any** "buttons" in your code. If you want a button, *use one*!

Comment: @Paulie_D i have added the buttons now

Comment: Does the below answer address your issue?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava yes thanks i will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to append the ids from clicked elements like below:

```js
$(function() {
  let creatingString = false, str;

  $("#B a, #Q a").click(function() {
    creatingString = true; str = "";
    str += $(this).parent().prop("id")
  })

  $("#Ag a, #Cli a").click(function() {
    if (!creatingString) return
    else {
      str += $(this).parent().prop("id")
      console.log("Selected ID:", str)
      
      $(".selected").removeClass("selected")
      $("#" + str).addClass("selected")
      
      creatingString = false
    }
  })
})
```

```css
div.selected {
  background: yellow;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist" data-tabs="tabs">
  <li id="B"><a href="#">B</a></li>
  <li id="Q"><a href="#">Q</a></li>
  <li id="Ag"><a href="#">Ag</a></li>
  <li id="Cli"><a href="#">Cli</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="BAg">BAg</div>
<div id="BCli">BCli</div>
<div id="QAg">QAg</div>
<div id="QCli">QCli</div>
```